# create a user login to comment in a blog

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a functionality in my website which should allow users to comment on a video or an image only after the user had logged in (very similar to the comment on a video after a sign in on YouTube). I have created the login control and a new user registration control using ASP controls. How do i integrate this to my comments.aspx page in which the user can view all previous comments that other users have commented but cannot comment until he signs in???
This is my login control:

```
        <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" FormatString="welcome page {0}">
        </asp:LoginName><br />
        <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />
    </LoggedInTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
```

Please help.

Jake

Answer (score 0):

You need to write yourself a mechanism that will check whether is your user logged in or not, and take actions based on that information. There are several ways to do it, for example you can switch visibility on your "post comment" button.